# Continuous distribution from data organized in intervals in R

Tags: r, intervals, cut, probability-density

I have the following problem. My data set is as follows:

```
Income              Numerosity
from 6000 to 7500       704790
from 7500 to 10000     1294784
from 10000 to 12000    1051902
from 12000 to 15000    1585132
from 15000 to 20000     704012
from 20000 to 25000     206901
from 25000 to 30000     156661
```

I would like to approximate these data with a continuous density function. 
Is there an easy way to do this in R? I am thinking of something like an "inverse" process with respect to what is done by the function "cut".

Comment: @Arun Couldn't he just fit a model and interpolate from that?

Comment: FYI this type of data is called "interval censored" - that might help you when looking for existing methods.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? What would you want to use the resulting continuous density (assuming you were able to get it) for?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is concerns the understanding of statistics. (OP: "Thank you. But how can I do to fit a model?")

Comment: See my own answer below: what I am trying to understand is how I can obtain a density from data in the form expressed above _using R_.  I found a possible solution, although there might be a better way to do that. I definitely do _not_ want to fit the data with a parametric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way: first I used `sample(6000:7500, 704790, replace=TRUE)` for each row to create a vector of generated observation. Then I applied the function `density` to the vector and obtained the density function I was looking for. There are certainly better and more elegant methods, but this worked.

Comment: Note that this approach assumes the data are uniformly distributed within each interval. If that is what you want, this will be fine.

Comment: Data are not uniform. However, I have no information on data  distribution within each interval. Any suggestion on how to make more sensible assumption and improve my fit is welcome.